# select single row from database with 2 columns may contain data or can be null

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @bsLineCode int=4

select * from table where 
(BusinessLineCodeIDT  = @bsLineCode OR BusinessLineCodeIDT IS NULL)
```

It is giving me two rows

```
IDT BusinessLineCodeIDT  
0   NULL
0   98
```

But i want that when `BusinessLineCodeIDT`  is having value then the 2nd row is selected.

Comment: Show output what you want to get instead of that you provided. And are you using 2012 SQL-server?

Comment: I am getting correct result. check this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61a54f/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table
WHERE BusinessLineCodeIDT = @bsLineCode OR BusinessLineCodeIDT IS NULL
ORDER BY CASE WHEN BusinessLineCodeIDT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your where clause is correct? Do you want either the same line code *OR* businessline code idt is null?
You can do this:

```
    select TOP 1 * from table where 
    (BusinessLineCodeIDT  = @bsLineCode OR BusinessLineCodeIDT IS NULL) 
    ORDER BY BusinessLineCodeIDT Desc
```